# Trouble with swap method-java

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, swap

Hello everyone I am currently creating a program where I want to swap index 2 and 4. I have the code completed however I do not receive an output and when I run the program I do not receive an error

Here is what I have so fa:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] intArray = {2,4,6,8,10};
    }

    char[] intArray;
    void swap(int i, int j, int[] arr) {
        int t = arr[2];
        arr[2] = arr[4];
        arr[4] = t;
        System.out.println(intArray);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You never call `swap`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] intArray = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };
   new test().swap(1, 2, intArray); // use local array
}

// char[] intArray; not needed

private void swap(int i, int j, int[] arr) {
   int t = arr[i];
   arr[i] = arr[j];
   arr[j] = t;
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // print array passed in
}
```

Comment: Thank I see the mistake that I have made. How come the "char[] intArray" is not needed

Comment: 1) Its not visible from the `static` `main` method 2) It's a char array 3) It's not initialised - `intArray` in `main` is actually a different array

Answer (score 0):

Your `swap` method looks good, but it is never called.  It looks like it should be called from `main`.  The `main` method is static, and you don't have (or need) an instance of `test`, so include `static` in your `swap` method.  Add the call to `swap` in your `main` method.

Additionally, you don't use `i` and `j` in `swap` -- replace `2` with `i` and `4` with `j`.  Also, you never use `char[] intArray`, which is declared as an instance variable; it can be safely removed.

Answer (score 0):

You never actually call the `swap` method, so add to your `main` method:

```
new test().swap(-1, -1, intArray);
```

Or:

```
test testObj = new test();
testObj.swap(-1, -1, intArray);
```

Sending a primitive array to `PrintWriter` will just give the default output from `Object.toString`. To get the values of the elements of the array use `Arrays.toString`. So use:

```
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(intArray));
```